# Cannot identify mistake in computing Shannon entropy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, primes, entropy

According to this [blog](http://www.math-math.com/2020/10/entropy-of-primes.html), Shannon entropy of the prime numbers approaches `log_2(e) ≈ 1.442695` as the limit counting prime numbers approaches infinity. I wanted to see this for myself in Python using NumPy and SciPy.

Given `N` prime numbers I compute the Shannon entropy for the first, the first two, then the first three prime numbers, until the last iteration where all prime numbers are used. My hope was to see Shannon entropy approach `log_2(e)` as the number of primes increased. Instead I find disagreement between the SciPy and NumPy approach:

[image: Shannon Entropy against First N Prime Numbers]

Can you help me identify my mistake? Also, why does this result contradict the math blog?

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
from scipy.stats import entropy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def get_shannon_entropy_via_scipy(prime_numbers):
    shannon_entropies = []
    for i in range(prime_numbers.size):
        shannon_entropies.append(
            entropy(prime_numbers[:i], base=2))
    return np.array(shannon_entropies)

def get_shannon_entropy_via_custom(prime_numbers):
    shannon_entropies = []
    for i in range(prime_numbers.size):
        variables = prime_numbers[:i]
        probabilities = np.ones(variables.size) / variables.size
        shannon_entropy = 0
        for p in probabilities:
            dentropy = p * np.log2(p)
            shannon_entropy -= dentropy
        shannon_entropies.append(shannon_entropy)
    return np.array(shannon_entropies)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    prime_numbers = np.array(list(sp.primerange(0, 1000)))

    shannon_entropy_via_scipy = get_shannon_entropy_via_scipy(prime_numbers)
    shannon_entropy_via_custom = get_shannon_entropy_via_custom(prime_numbers)

    print("\n{} Prime Numbers {} - {}\n".format(
        prime_numbers.size,
        prime_numbers[0],
        prime_numbers[-1]))

    # for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(shannon_entropy_via_scipy, shannon_entropy_via_custom)):
    #     if x != y:
    #         print("\ni={}\nscipy={}\ncustom={}\n".format(i, x, y))

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(
        prime_numbers,
        shannon_entropy_via_scipy,
        marker='.',
        color='darkorange',
        label='via scipy',
        alpha=0.8)
    ax.plot(
        prime_numbers,
        shannon_entropy_via_custom,
        marker='.',
        color='steelblue',
        label='via custom',
        alpha=0.8)
    fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
    fig.legend(mode='expand', loc='lower center', ncol=2)
    plt.show()
    plt.close(fig)
```

The xlabel of the plot should read "First 1000 Numbers" as there are 168 primes less than 1000 (the greatest of which is 997).

Comment: In `get_shannon_entropy_via_scipy`, you are passing the actual values from `prime_numbers` into `entropy`.  In `get_shannon_entropy_via_custom`, the calculation of the entropy uses only the size of the array (i.e. `variables.size`).

Comment: You are better to summarize that blog and write it in the question, in case of that link being broken.

Comment: That blog MEANINGLESSLY defines 'the entropy of prime numbers up to N' to be (the number of prime numbers up to N) * (the entropy of random variable x taking values in {1, 2, ..., N} and being in a uniform distribution)/N. Your code calling ```scipy.stats.entropy()``` on prime numbers is totally different from that weird definition and is also meaningless. Your code summing ```-p * np.log2(p)``` is similar to that weird definition but you are using set of prime numbers, not {1, 2, ..., N}.